# How do you get the max value in a tensorflow dataset whilst keeping the same shape and dimension?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Consider the following code below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.constant([5, 1, 2, 4])
tf.reduce_max(x)
```

The result of the above would give me the output x:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=5>
```

However, I want to get the max value in such a format:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(4,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([5,5,5,5]dtype=int32)>
```

Any ideas how to code this?

Comment: Try `tf.repeat(tf.reduce_max(x), repeats=x.shape[0])`.

Comment: `tf.reduce_max(x, keepdims=True)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Flavia Giammarino for helping.

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.constant([5, 1, 2, 4])
tf.reduce_max(x)


test=tf.repeat(tf.reduce_max(x), repeats=x.shape[0])
print(test)
```

I got the following output as desired:

```
tf.Tensor([5 5 5 5], shape=(4,), dtype=int32)
```